# Not able to perform the vertical scrolling

Tags: java, selenium

I want to click on a web-element and  perform some action .For the that the element needs to be visible . I have written the below code . Which work is to perform the vertical scroll up to the web-element is not visible . But the problem is , the code is scrolling beyond the element and the element is going up . I want to scroll  up to the web-element .

**The below code i have written for vertical scroll up to the web-element is visible**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div//span[@title='Brand']"));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
        Thread.sleep(500);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A good approach to solve this would be to:

1. Check if the element is visible

```
protected boolean isElementPresent(WebElement element) {
       try {
           element.isDisplayed();
           return true;
       } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
           return false;
       }
   }
```

2. If the element is visible then perform your action.

```
public void scroll() {
       while (!isElementPresent(element)) {
           doSomething();
           sleep(1000);
       }
   }
```

3. Define your action

```
protected void doSomething() {
       WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div//span[@title='Brand']"));
       ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
   }
```